# How to install windows from Ubuntu 12.04 with no partition dedicated to Windows?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, windows-7, hard-drive

Essentially when I originally installed ubuntu, I got rid of my windows and had the hard drive reformatted.  I never split up the hard drive to dual boot.  Now that the hard drive is formatted for linux...how to I get some space available to be able to dual boot?  It won't let me partition when I'm using the hard drive that is associated with the operating system.  Please help.

Comment: use virtualbox and intall windows inside it. this is the safer way

Comment: Running in virtualbox is maybe safer than resizing partitions, but it's also way slower and more restricted.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Virtual Machine, for example with VirtualBox, and installing Windows on it it's a good and safe alternative; if your CPU supports VT-x it should run almost fast as a real machine.

But this way you will always have to start Ubuntu before start Windows, this generally it's ok, but depends on your needings.

So if you don't want to use virtualization, you should download a "Parted Magic" ISO image, burn on a CD, and boot from this : the GParted software included will let you resize and create partitions.

Comment: I'll be using a flash drive...I'll try part 2 later this evening.  But what file type is the flash drive needed to be formatted to? Ext3? Ext4? linux-swap?  This is part of my problem as well.  What format to format it to.  Newbie here but learning fast.

Comment: For Windows use a NTFS partition. So you have to reduce size of current ext4 partition, and in free size create a NTFS partition.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 possibilities:

1. GParted is used to change the Linux partitioning (decreasing the size of ). You need some space on one of the Linux partitions.
2. Use Oracle Virtual Box on Linux (or similar software) and install Windows into a virtual machine.

Method 1 is more risky. You boot from your Windows cd and install Windows on the newly created partition. Windows does not care of other oses and I don't remember if Windows
will not screw up the Linux boot loader... If you can avoid Windows to touch the Linux boot loader configuration (grub) then you can later add the Windows os from Linux...

Comment: #1 doesn't work since the partition I'm editing is the one I'm working off of it.  It won't allow me to do so.

Comment: #2 I did but when I partition part of the hard drive for use of windows I used 50 GBs and then when on the windows virtual machine I shrunk the partition and now had two partitions in windows that were basically 25 and 25 ntsf drives.  But when I tried to install windows using boot menu from the usb drive, it doesn't recognize the extra 25 gbs ntsf that I made available for windows to use as space.  It just groups all of the machine ntsf and new ntsf into the actual linux drive that I'm trying to partition in the first place.

Comment: #1 is of course possible for systems with only1  partition... In this case you have to boot from the gparted live cd... You burn an iso from your Ubuntu system and then boot from the cd. You will then have access to GParted...